# Tradução de "Bounty" seria melhor "Recompensa" ou "Gratificação" mesmo?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, recompensa

Qual seria a melhor tradução para "Bounty" ?

Na minha opinião "Recompensa" ficaria melhor que "Gratificação" o que vocês acham?

Comment: A favor de recompensa: a tag "recompensa" aqui do meta já é sinônima do original "bounty".

Comment: As ocorrências de "gratificação" (e variações) estão sendo gradualmente passadas para "recompensa" mas é um trabalho lento e tedioso.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Concordo.

http://translate.google.com/#en/pt/bounty

"Gratificação" nem aparece como sinônimo.

Comment: O google não nos deixa mentir que "Recompensa" é melhor

Comment: Não que o google translate seja a autoridade máxima em sinônimos, mas ok. Eu estou confortável com qualquer uma das traduções.

Comment: É uma boa autoridade, sobretudo porque é colaborativo (aceita sugestões). E outra: http://translate.google.com/#pt/en/gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Como é que vamos traduzir "array", conforme o Google? http://translate.google.com.br/#en/pt/array - "Matriz" nem aparece como sinônimo.

Answer (score 10):

Gratificação, ao menos para os brasileiros, pode soar como algo relacionado a adições extras ao salário devido a alguma cláusula em contrato de trabalho. Para mim só remete a burocracia em cima de folhas de pagamento. Sou a favor de que o termo seja mudado para "recompensa".

Comment: ótimo ponto de vista, concordo plenamente

Answer (score 2):

Existem outras opções, como "**Bônus**" ou "**Premiação**".

"**Bônus**" é particularmente atraente por ter semelhança com o original "**Bounty**".

---

Conforme o "*Novo Dicionário Folha Websters Inglês/Português Português/Inglês*", editado por Antônio Houaiss e publicado pela PubliFolha em 1996:

**bounty** generosidade, liberalidade; doação, favor; recompensa; concessão; abono; gratificação

**bonus** bonificação, abono; prêmio; dividendo; suborno

Em ambos temos "abono", mas podemos ver que a semelhança no significado vai além, se consideramos que "recompensa" equivale a "prêmio", "gratificação" equivale a "bonificação"...

---

Vejamos agora o [artigo na Wikipedia explicando Bounty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounty_%28reward%29):

- logo no início está dizendo que vem do latim ***bonitās***
- a seção sobre futebol americano começa dizendo: "***Bounties***, referring to **bonuses** for in-game performance (...)"
- a seção sobre recutamento começa dizendo: "*'**Bounty**' is also used to refer to **bonus** payments (...)*"

---

Agora sigamos um passo adiante e vejamos o que quer dizer ***bonitās*** - palavra em latim que dá origem a "*bounty*" - conforme "[An Elementary Latin Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=bonitas)", de Charlton T. Lewis:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

"**Bonus**" aparece como o primeiro significado na lista!

[Adentrando mais nos links desse dicionário latim](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=bonus&la=la&can=bonus0&prior=bonit%C4%81s&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=bonitas&i=1#lexicon), vemos que um dos usos para o termo *bonus* efetivamente utilizado na literatura em latim que consta na base de dados é "*honorable achievement*" - "realização honrosa" - que para mim transmite bem a essência de conquistar os pontos extras na reputação que são conquistados através do "*bounty*": uma "realização honrosa"...

---

Em suma: **Bounty** vem de ***bonitās*** e ***bonitās*** quer dizer **bônus**.

Com certeza "Bônus" é uma boa opção de tradução para "*Bounty*".

[Talvez o Google não seja um tradutor tão bom assim...](http://translate.google.com.br/#pt/en/Talvez%20o%20Google%20n%C3%A3o%20seja%20um%20tradutor%20t%C3%A3o%20bom%20assim...)

Comment: Mas `Bônus` é tradução de `Bonus`, um caso onde a similaridade é uma armadilha (pense em `Puxe` e `Push`).

Comment: O verbo `push` em inglês é `empurrar` em português (uma armadilha, pois parece que seria `puxar`, que em inglês é `pull` - e `pular` é `jump`). Qual o paralelo com `bônus`? Qual é a tradução de `bonus` (em inglês) para o português? Não é `bônus`? Conferi no Google Translator e me diz que é isso mesmo: `bonus` = `bônus`. Onde está a armadilha?

Comment: Minha menção foi em relação à similaridade entre 'Bônus' e 'Bounty'.

Comment: Fui tentar descobrir onde estava a "armadilha"... acrescentei o resultado da pesquisa à resposta.