# Melhora na tradução de motivo para criar uma recompensa

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Ao tentar abrir uma **recompensa** vejo a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela tem dois erros:

1. O nome é "recompensa", não "gratificação". Como discutido na [**pergunta 666**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/666/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bounty-seria-melhor-recompensa-ou-gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mesmo), a mudança foi feita, mas esse título aqui foi esquecido.
2. "Chamou atenção" não faz sentido como motivo. O correto é "Chamar atenção", vide a descrição logo abaixo.

Em um diálogo anterior também existe a inconsistência entre "recompensa" e "gratificação":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Relativamente à primeira questão, penso que "Chamar atenção" é sem duvida a forma correta de descrever o pretendido. Ainda mais se reforçado com o que se lê na descrição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[(c) http://salesmomsnetwork.com](http://salesmomsnetwork.com/2010/07/direct-sales-marketing-call-attention-to-peoples-mistakes-indirectly/)</sup>

Assim sendo:

> **Chamar Atenção**
>   Esta pergunta não recebeu atenção suficiente.

---

Em relação ao segundo tópico, de facto, "Gratificação" nunca me fez muito sentido, menos ainda atendendo ao seu [contexto "real"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que se aplica no direito do trabalho brasileiro, descrevendo um valor financeiro atribuído a um funcionário a titulo de motivação.

Já a palavra "Recompensa" está diretamente ligada ao termo original "Bounty" e mantém a *piada* por trás do ato realizado.

Tal como no seu contexto "real", o que estamos a fazer é oferecer X para que alguém realize Y:

[image: Jango Fett Attack of the Clones - Star Wars Artfx Statue]

<sup>[(c) staractionfigures.co.uk](http://www.staractionfigures.co.uk/603259028278.html)</sup>

Comment: Muito bom... mas não entendi a segunda figura! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Jango Fett, o famoso bounty hunter da saga Star Wars vai certamente recolher todas as "recompensas" do Sopt :P Ou pelo menos era a piada que tentava transmitir...

Comment: Sou um zero à esquerda em star wars...

Comment: Hehe eu só reconheci a figura por causa do chapéu do *winter bash* do ano passado... :P